# IMCE directory per user

Tags: 7, files

I'm working on a scenario where users should not be able to access others' files. So, I wrote a custom module that creates a folder names user's name, then I went on to /admin/config/media/imce to set permissions and I typed `php: return 'users/'.$user->name` as instructed on the same page. However, that gives me `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in DRUPAL_ROOT/sites/all/modules/imce/inc/imce.page.inc(789) : eval()'d code on line 1` and `There is no valid directory specified for the file browser!`. What to do? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a syntax error, generated because you're missing some parenthesis or other required syntax. Do you have a semicolon at the end of return 'users/'.$user->name? 
Should be: 
`'users/'.$user->name;`

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked something so obvious! Thank you :)

Comment: No problem at all, we've all been there ;)